# Selecting available timeslots for a specific date

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get a list of all available timeslots for a specific date by left joining my timeslot table with me schedule table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `timeslots` 
LEFT JOIN schedule ON timeslots.timeslot_id = schedule.schedule_timeslot 
LIMIT 0, 30
```

This returns:

[image]

What I want returned are all the rows that are null for the last 3 fields.  So given the date 2011-08-01 I want all the timeslots returned except for 08:30 - 10:30.  I'm assuming some sort of sub-query is needed but I don't know how to go about it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `timeslots` 
LEFT JOIN schedule ON timeslots.timeslot_id = schedule.schedule_timeslot
WHERE  schedule.schedule_id IS NULL or schedule.schedule_date <> '2011-08-01'
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a WHERE

```
SELECT * 
FROM `timeslots` 
LEFT JOIN schedule ON timeslots.timeslot_id = schedule.schedule_timeslot 
WHERE schedule.schedule_timeslot IS NULL
LIMIT 0, 30
```

Comment: But I believe that removes the timeslot for 2011-08-02 as well and I don't want that. Only the ones for 2011-08-01 or some arbitrary date.  - Thanks

Comment: @PhoenixDown: you said "What I want returned are all the rows that are null for the last 3 fields". I've done that. Fix your question please