# MySQL PHP Get the inverse times from a database table

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time

So I have 2 tables, a user table and an appointments table. What I want to be able to do is get the times out of the database that don't exist.

I will give a couple of examples as that may not make any sense, below are my 2 tables.

```
+-----------------+
|      Users      |
+-----------------+
|  ID  |   Name   |
+------+----------+
|  1   |   Bill   |
|  2   |   John   |
+------+----------+

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                   Appointments                          |   
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|  UserID  |    DateTimeFrom    |    DateTimeTo     |   AppointmentName   |     
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
|     1    |  2012-06-16 10:00  |  2012-06-16 11:00 |      Hair Cut       |
|     1    |  2012-06-16 14:30  |  2012-06-16 16:00 |         Work        |
|     1    |  2012-06-16 19:00  |  2012-06-16 22:00 |  Dinner and Drinks  |
|     2    |  2012-06-16 07:00  |  2012-06-16 10:30 |      Travelling     |
|     2    |  2012-06-16 16:00  |  2012-06-16 16:30 |        Dentist      |
+----------+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

What I want to get back out is the empty or inverse time, so for example if I was just doing it for Bill on the 16th June then what I want returning is:

```
+--------------+------------+
|   TimeFrom   |   TimeTo   |
+--------------+------------+
|    00:00     |    10:00   |
|    11:00     |    14:30   |
|    16:00     |    19:00   |
|    22:00     |    23:59   |
+--------------+------------+
```

And if I was doing it for both users on the 16th June then I would get something like:

```
+--------------+------------+
|   TimeFrom   |   TimeTo   |
+--------------+------------+
|    00:00     |    07:00   |
|    11:30     |    14:30   |
|    16:30     |    19:00   |
|    22:00     |    23:59   |
+--------------+------------+
```

Or something as close to that as possible. I don't know if there is a good way to do it in MySQL or if I will have to use PHP to convert the times to their invert.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which code you have write for this..please write here.

Comment: You can refer to this link for a start http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222565/selecting-available-timeslots-for-a-specific-date

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this in mysql directly except possibly with a stored function

Comment: I haven't written any code yet as I can't get my head around it at all. I didn't think there was a way to directly do it in MySQL but I was hoping I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware there is no functionality in mysql to handle this directly, however it is very easy to handle in PHP.

If you do not have any events which span from one day to the other, then all you need to do is put all of the times in to an array in sequence (start,end,start,end,start,end ...) then array_unshift '00:00' on to the start, array_push '23:59' on to the end, then array_chunk it by two and you'll have the output you want.

If you do have events which span from one day to another, then you take the same approach but use timestamps, replacing 00:00 with the timestamp for the start of the first day, and 23:59 with the timestamp for the end of the last day.

Apologies for not posting the code, but I feel the approach is better explained than simply delivering code to do it in this case.

Comment: This is a really good idea but I can't get my head around how this would work querying all of the users. How can I combine all of the times together when different users have times that overlap?